# Work with methods, setters and getters in java

Tags: java, instantiation

I have this class:

```
public class Person
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String firstName = "Vasya";
    private String lastName = "Pupkin";
    private Integer age = 58;
    private Integer phone = 2;

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        firstName = name;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lName)
    {
        lastName = lName;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer personAge)
    {
        age = personAge;
    }

    public void setPhone(Integer personPhone)
    {
        phone = personPhone;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Integer getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public Integer getPhone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        this.setName("");
        this.setLastName("");
        this.setPhone(0);
        this.setAge(0);
    }
}
```

I create an variable: `Person somePerson`, then I call method `setName` from that variable `somePerson`:

```
somePerson.setName("");
```

but it raises an error.

Comment: Do you initialize your `Person` object? Are you doing `Person somePerson; somePerson.setName("");`?

Comment: Re "Then I create an variable with type `Person`", do you actually create a `new Person` anywhere or is the "variable" a field with that has its default value of `null`?

Comment: Why do you have an `Init` method instead of initializing state in a constructor?

Comment: Re "There is my error", where?

Comment: Thanks for all, I've been forgot to use constructor new.

Comment: change you getters and setters to use the "this" keyword in front of them, such as this.firstName = name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the provided code, the following should work:

```
Person somePerson = new Person();
somePerson.setName("");
```

If it doesn't, then something else is going on.